# How can get Net Seller by using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
    enter code here

<div class="_1hVBfR">
   <span class="row _1kkfO3 BqOr_g">Google Nest Mini (2nd Gen) with Google A...</span>
   <div class="row _65ZkAB">
      <span class="_3dOR_a">
      <span class="_65ZkAB">Color: </span>
      <span class="-igymY">Black</span></span>
      <span class="_3dOR_a"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="row _65ZkAB">
      <span class="_65ZkAB _1uABhR">Seller: </span>
      <span class="-igymY">Net Seller</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can i get net seller as the output value.
Since the class name is same for both Black and Net seller i am getting  only black.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `soup.find_all()` to select all `span` then select desire output using index.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="_1hVBfR">
   <span class="row _1kkfO3 BqOr_g">Google Nest Mini (2nd Gen) with Google A...</span>
   <div class="row _65ZkAB">
      <span class="_3dOR_a">
      <span class="_65ZkAB">Color: </span>
      <span class="-igymY">Black</span></span>
      <span class="_3dOR_a"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="row _65ZkAB">
      <span class="_65ZkAB _1uABhR">Seller: </span>
      <span class="-igymY">Net Seller</span>
   </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

res = soup.find_all('span', {'class': '-igymY'})[1]

print(res.text)

res = soup.find_all('span', {'class': '-igymY'})

print([t.text  for t in res if t.text == 'Net Seller'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS Selector:

```
print(soup.select_one(".row > span.-igymY").text)
```

Or:

access the second element of the `list` returned by `find_all()`.

```
print(soup.find_all('span', class_='-igymY')[1].text)
```

Output:

```
Net Seller
```